# Trying to use Javascript to post json

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send some data to update a session variable using ajax.  I have it working from jquery but I'm trying to understand how to do it using javascript.  It almost works but there is a problem with how I am passing the data, and I can't figure out what is wrong.

here is the javascript

```
  document.getElementsByClassName('page-link').forEach(function(pagelink) {
    pagelink.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var data = {questions:localStorage.getItem('formValues')};
      let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('POST', '/default', true);
      request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
      request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    })
  });
```

localStorage.getItem('formValues') is generated earlier from:

```
formValues[checkbox.id] = checkbox.checked;
localStorage.setItem('formValues', JSON.stringify(formValues));
```

When I examine my data object in the console it looks like this:
{questions: "{"test1":true}"}

but when is send it using JSON.stringify(data) the whole object becomes the key and there is no value being sent.

Here is what the key looks like according to the symfony profiler:

{"questions":"{\"test1\":true,\"test2\":true}"}

There is probably a very simple explanation to what I am doing wrong but I cannot figure it out!

Pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

I have simplified things to

```
  document.getElementById('btn-send').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var data = {questions:"test"};
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', '/default', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
```

and I have exactly the same issue. I have also tried:
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json') but that did not work either?

Here is a picture of the symfony profiler for the ajax request:

[image]

Thanks
Martyn

Comment: jquery *is* javascript, so if you have it working with jquery, you have it working with javascript.

Comment: If you're sending JSON, you want the Content-Type to be `application/json`, not `application/x-www/form/urlencoded`.

Comment: theres no `forEach` on the `NodeList` returned by `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: The reason being it doesn't return a `NodeList` at all, it returns an `HTMLCollection` (and we've not be able to get rid of it for historical reasons)

Comment: okay, if I just use the first element of that collection I still get exactly the same problem?  I don't think that is the source of my problem, it is to do with the was it is mangling my object before it is sent.

Comment: If I look at the result of console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); it looks like: {"questions":"{\"test1\":true}"}, which is being sent as the key

Answer (score 0):

I have found a fix [enter link description here](https://plainjs.com/javascript/ajax/send-ajax-get-and-post-requests-47/)

It was as I suspected that the json was becoming mangled when stringified.  The above link uses the following code:

```
function postAjax(url, data, success) {
    var params = typeof data == 'string' ? data : Object.keys(data).map(
            function(k){ return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k]) }
        ).join('&');

    var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState>3 && xhr.status==200) { success(xhr.responseText); }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(params);
    return xhr;
}
```

This question can be closed.